# Formula to set Date/Time to EOD using CreatedDate

Tags: formula, case, formula-field

I have a requirement to report on cases that are not resolved by 6:00PM Local (end of support day).

If the case comes in before 6:00PM then it must be closed by 6:00PM same day. If it comes in between 6:01PM it must be closed by 6:00PM the next day.

I'd like to avoid code and accomplish this declaratively if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Formula Field like this:

`IF(Case.CreatedDate - DATETIMEVALUE( DATEVALUE(DATE(Case.CreatedDate)) & " 18:00:00") > 0,
   IF( //Case created after 6
     OR(
       DATE(Case.CloseDate) > (DATE(Case.CreatedDate) + 1), //Case closed after the day after creation
       Case.CloseDate - DATETIMEVALUE( DATEVALUE(DATE(Case.CloseDate)) & " 18:00:00") > 0 //Case closed the day after, but after 6)
     ), 0, 1),
   IF(
     OR(
       DATE(Case.ClosedDate) = DATE(Case.ClosedDate), 
       Case.ClosedDate - DATETIMEVALUE( DATEVALUE(DATE(Case.ClosedDate)) & " 18:00:00") <= 0
     ), 1, 0 
   )
)`

Comment: (this gives you 1 for "good cases" and 0 for bad ones - haven't tested it, just wrote in here ;-)

Comment: It's giving me a few errors. I am going to try to get it working.

Comment: No luck yet? I'm sorry I did not verify the Formula before handing it over to you, but I was about to start a meeting and had to be quick yesterday :-) I think the underlying mechanism fits the requirements anyway, regardless of any mistake in the Formula I posted.

Comment: It was a good start. I had to adjust for 12 hour. I haven't had the chance to tie it all together yet.